# HTML form to then redirect to the contents of the form

Tags: php, html

this is gonna sound kind of weird but this is what I am trying to do.
Essentially, I wish to have an HTML form, where someone enters text into it, and it will then redirect to mydomain.com/theirtext I have tried several things to do this, and none have worked. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="padding:16px;">
    TextBox : <input type="textbox" id="userValue" value=""></input>
</div>

var url = "http://java67.blogspot.com";
var useraddedText=$("#userValue").val();
$(location).attr('href',url+"/"+useraddedText);
```

try the above code. Its just a sample but this should work..

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery:

```
<form id="goToPathForm">
    <input type="textbox" id="goToPath" value="" />
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>

window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {

    document.getElementById( 'goToPathForm' ).addEventListener( 'submit', function( se ) {

        submitEvent.stopPropagation(); // also invokes `preventDefault()`
        window.location = '/' + document.getElementById( 'goToPath' ).value;
    } );
} );
```

Comment: how would you go about implementing this?

Comment: @LazarusHoll I just did implement it for you, you just need to copy+paste my code into your website. If you don't know how to place JavaScript and HTML on your webpage then I think you're getting ahead of yourself and you should familiarize yourself with more of the basics.

Comment: I probably am! I didnt mean to sound annoying, sorry, just trying to setup this little thing for my site.